# "For detailed review and comparison "

Tags: indefinite-articles, parallelism

I would be so grateful if you can let me know which of the following sentences is correct:

1: "For **a** detailed review of the most related works and **a** comparison between them "

2: "For detailed review of the most related works and comparison between them "

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Neither seems clear, largely because as it is 'most related' doesn't seem to mean anything.

'For a detailed review of the works most related to the subject and a comparison between them…'might work, if that's what you mean.

'For a detailed review of the works and a comparison between them…'would be fine by itself.

'For detailed review of the works and comparison between them…' lacks clarity

'For detailed reviews of the works and comparisons/ a comparison between them…' would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Either could be correct, they just mean slightly different things.

The first refers to a single review:

> For a detailed review of the most related works and a comparison between them, read A.N.Other's monograph *My Detailed Review of Most Related Works*.

The second refers to a collection or ongoing series of separate reviews:

> For detailed review of the most related works and comparison between them, read *The Journal of Detailed Reviews*, with more of the most related works covered every week.

or possibly

> For detailed review of the most related works and comparison between them, attend my weekly seminars on Tuesday at 4pm.

Note that *detailed review* and *comparison* are both singular in the second case because they're talking about the act of performing a review or comparison, so these acts are ongoing.